# Mapping classes from Assemblies which are stored in a Different Folder

Tags: c#, nhibernate, mef, fluent

I'm trying to build an extensible application using MEF and fluent Nhibernate as ORM.
It was working well until I decided to store the extension assemblies in a seperate folder 
(\Extensions). MEF loads the extensions without any problem, but
nhibernate throws exceptions because it can't locate the assembly.

Is there a way to add the Extensions Folder to the Assembly searchpath?

MEF Composition:

```
[ImportMany]
public IEnumerable<IModule> Modules { get; private set; }

public void LoadModules()
{
    _initialized = false;
    var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog("Extensions");
    var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
    container.ComposeParts(this);

}
```

Mapping:

```
foreach (var module in modules)
{
    var assembly = module.GetType().Assembly;
    config.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(assembly));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, there are a couple of options:

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.PrivateBinPath` will work if your Extension directory is or is in a subdirectory of the application's directory.

Alternatively, you could handle the `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event.

Comment: Thank you! I've found another solution using the app.config `<runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <probing privatePath="extensions"/>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>`